# Jython getting TypeError: Supertypes that share a modified attribute have an MRO conflict

Tags: junit, filenet-p8, filenet, jython-2.7, filenet-content-engine

I am working on IBM FileNet P8 Platform 5.2.1 Content Engine unit test application in jython 2.7.

```
# Verify a directory
def testDirectory(self):
    directoryConfigurationList = [] 
    url = self.serverUrl + "?tenantId=" + self.tenantName  
    connection = Factory.Connection.getConnection(url)
    domain = Factory.Domain.fetchInstance(connection, self.tenantName, None)
    if (domain is not None):
        dc_set = domain._DirectoryConfigurations.iterator()
        while dc_set.hasNext():
            dc = dc_set.next()
            print dc._DisplayName
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Supertypes that share a modified attribute have an MRO
>   conflict[attribute=remove, supertypes=[,  'com.filenet.api.collection.DependentObjectList'>],
>   type=CmIndexPartitionConstraintList]

on line  **dc_set = domain._DirectoryConfigurations.iterator()** and I don't quite now why. Any help on this would be appreciated. The following links to the IBM 5.2.1 knowledge center maybe helpful:

- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/collection/DirectoryConfigurationList.html
- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/collection/DependentObjectList.html?view=embed

Comment: From what I understand, it seem like Jython is trying to implement its version of lists while this is already a list type defined in DependentObjectList which DirectoryConfigurations is inherited from. I think...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your fileNet code, it looks like Jython doesn't expect to ever see a Map that is also Iterable. I presume it has logic that installs **iter** on each and then gets a conflict. Unfortunately, there's nothing incorrect about a type that implements both Map and Iterable. Jython should defer to Iterable for **iter**, but it looks like it will need and enhancement in order to do so.

If you check the `DependentObjectList` Interface specification, you would see in the super type interfaces that its super type interfaces are `java.util.Collection, EngineCollection, java.lang.Iterable, java.util.List, java.io.Serializable`.

I believe that this was fixed potentially since Jython 2.7b1.

**Update:**
I have been doing some digging on a code that we developed before in Java, we used the following logic to convert the engine collection to a list-based collection

```
public static <T> List<T> convertToList(EngineCollection engineCollection) {
    Iterator<T> engineCollectionIterator = engineCollection.iterator();
    List<T> collection = new ArrayList<T>();
    CollectionUtils.addAll(collection , engineCollectionIterator);
    return collection ;
}
```

Comment: What blows my mind is that I also see this for List/Collection. "TypeError: Supertypes that share a modified attribute have an MRO conflict[attribute=__contains__, supertypes=[<type 'java.util.Collection'>, <type 'java.util.Set'>], type=...]" We're on 2.7.2b2 though, so I don't think it has been fixed.